Visual Studio Keeps Falling Back to MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.11 After Uninstall Then Installing MySql.Data.EntityFramework 9.0.0.0
I hope you can provide some light on this issue.
I'm running Visual Studio 2019 on a C# web applicacation, a few days ago, I updated all the packages using Nuget because I was getting the following error:
Method not found: 'Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(System.String)'.
Updating did not work, however I openned Web.Config and found the following error in the  tag:
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  **<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, 
            Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
</providers></providers>**

  

    
    
      
      **
    **
  
It happens that when Nuget install the provider for MySql.Data.MySqlClient the tag is not closed properly and creates an error, so I did the following:
**<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, 
            Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</providers>**

This fixed the error in the Web. Config and the app worked fine for a few tries, however, the error returned, when I checked the Web.Config file, I found that the tag for the provider MySql.Data.MySqlClient undo the changes I made and the tag was again on error state:
**<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, 
            Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
</providers></providers>**

So I decided to update the MySql.Data.EntityFramework to it's latest version 9.0.0.0, after this, everything works fine, however, every time I Build the application or close it and reopen it, the provider for MySql.Data.MySqlClient returns to version 8.0.11.0 t=and the error returns.
Any thoughts?
